# Performance Impact of Triggers and MultiTriggers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance

At work, a question arose in regards to the performance impact of having a MultiTrigger in the ListBoxItem ControlTemplate.

The situation goes a bit like this: we have a custom styling for the ListBox control that defines an animation and color for the selected ListBoxItem. The issue arose because when the ListBox is disabled, we do not want the selected ListBoxItem to show the selected "background" highlight. This led us to add a set of triggers in the ControlTemplate of ListBoxItems to disable this custom highlighting when the ListBoxItem is disabled and selected. This is where the worry for a negative performance impact originated:

If every ListBoxItem needs to check for triggers and activate for triggers, would this generate a **noticeable** performance impact if there were a lot of items. This could be an issue because this code runs on **older** computers.

Comment: Are you using any of these: MVVM, MVC, MVP?

Comment: It shouldn't - triggers are usually simple comparisons, unless you've got a very expensive converter. Plus, virtualization should be enabled on the listbox, making the triggers only active for the visible items. Profile your code, if you have performance problems with WPF, triggers probably aren't the cause.

Comment: @oleksii this application uses MVVM.

Comment: @JulienLebosquain is virtualization always enabled by default.

Comment: @AlexanderVentura please see the answer by HighCore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number one WPF does not support "older computers".

Number two if your `ListBox` is Virtualized (which is the default behavior unless you break it by not using a `VirtualizingStackPanel` or by putting the `ListBox` in and infinite container (such as another `StackPanel`) the `ListBoxItems` are NOT created until they are scrolled into view by the user, in which case regardless of having 1000000000 items in the ListBox only the ones that fit into the screen are actually created and consuming memory + CPU.